# Accessing Cloud SQL from Cloud Build

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-build

I want to configure `CI/CD` from `Cloud Repositories` that builds my `CMS` (Directus) when I push to main repository.

In the build-time, the project needs to access `Cloud SQL`. But I get this error:
[image]

I tried this database configuration with `gcloud app deploy` and it connects `Cloud SQL` and runs.

`cloudbuild.yaml` (It crashes at second step, so I didn't add other steps for simplicity):

```
steps:

- name: node:16
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
  dir: cms

- name: node:16
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'start']
  dir: cms
  env:
  - 'NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION'
  - 'EXTENSIONS_PATH="./extensions"'
  - 'DB_CLIENT=pg'
  - 'DB_HOST=/cloudsql/XXX:europe-west1:XXX'
  - 'DB_PORT="5432"'
  - 'DB_DATABASE="XXXXX"'
  - 'DB_USER="postgres"'
  - 'DB_PASSWORD="XXXXXX"'
  - 'KEY="XXXXXXXX"'
  - 'SECRET="XXXXXXXXXXXX"'
```

`Node-pg` (node library) adds `/.s.PGSQL.5432` at the end automatically. That's why it is not written in `DB_HOST`.

`IAM` roles:
[image]

How can I solve this error? I read so many answers in Stackoverflow but none of them helped me. I found this article but I didn't fully understand how to implement it in my case (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-build).

Comment: The link you posted is the answer. What specifically you didn't understand? On the other hand using your approach, you may need to allow `0.0.0.0/0` on Cloud SQL (not recomended)

Comment: Additionally to this you're trying to connect to a UNIX socket, are you sure the socket is connected to the instance?

Answer (score 1):

Without your full Cloud Build yaml, it's hard to say for sure - but, it looks like you [aren't following the steps in the documentation correctly](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-build).

Roughly what you should be doing is:

1. Downloading the `cloud_sql_proxy` into your container space
2. In a follow up step, start the cloud_sql_proxy then (in the same step) run your script, connecting to the proxy via either tcp or unix socket.

I don't see your yaml describing the proxy at all.